# Cannot save user input to the database in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am developing an app that saves the user input to the database. However, for some reasons, I cannot see the data that has been been by the user when he pressed the Save Button. Can you help me save the values from this codes?

**activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spn_District"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spn_Province"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spn_InfoType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_Remarks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Cons_IReport.java (Constructor)**

```
public Cons_iReport(String district, String province, String infoType, String rDateObserved, String rRemarks){
    this._district = district;
    this._province = province;
    this._infoType = infoType;
    this._dateObserved = rDateObserved;
    this._remarks = rRemarks;
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public void SaveReport(Cons_iReport save){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_DISTRICT, save.getDistrict()); 
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_PROVINCE, save.getProvince()); 
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_INFOTYPE, save.getInfoType()); 
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_DATEOBSERVED, save.getDateObserved()); 
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_REMARKS, save.getRemarks());

    db.insert(Constants.TABLE_REPORT, null, values);
    db.close(); 
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
btn_Save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String rDistrict = spn_District.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String rProvince = spn_Province.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String rInfoType = spn_InfoType.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String rDateObserved = txt_Date.getText().toString();
            String rRemarks = txt_Remarks.getText().toString();

            databaseHandler.SaveReport(new Cons_iReport(rDistrict, rProvince, rInfoType, rDateObserved, rRemarks));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED!\n" + rDistrict + "\n" + rProvince + "\n" + rInfoType +  "\n" + rDateObserved + "\n" + rRemarks, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will sound wrong but don't db.close.  Subsequent calls to getWritableDatabase will return the same, already closed, object.  It may also effect your ability to read from the database if the same underlying now closed object is used.

Pull the db file off your emulator and open it in a SQLite editor http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/ works but if you can find a better one use it.

Are there any rows in the table in that database?

Also for debugging purposes try insertOrThrow instead of insert then you'll get an exception if the insert fails instead of it failing silently.